Fabric8 maven plugin always initiated even though the profile it's inside doesn't get activated
I have this profile in my pom.xml:
<profile>
    <id>decoupledPipelineProfile</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <property>
            <name>decoupledPipeline</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <build>
                                <dockerFile>${project.basedir}/docker/Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                                <contextDir>${project.basedir}</contextDir>
                                <tags>
                                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                                </tags>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>

Initially I didn't have the src/main folder and all was fine - no usage of fabric8 plugin.
But when I added the src/main folder - then suddenly in the logs I see:
build   08-Oct-2024 06:58:48    [INFO] 
build   08-Oct-2024 06:58:48    [INFO] --- fabric8-maven-plugin:4.4.0:build (build-docker-image) @ poker-game-common ---

Why am I seeing this? ... Cause I think this profile should get activated only when the decoupledPipeline maven parameters is provided, no?

This works for me
   <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
         ...
         ...
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>decoupledPipelineProfile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>decoupledPipeline</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
         ...
         ...
    </profiles>

Run with fabric
mvn clean install -DdecoupledPipeline=true

Run without fabric
mvn clean install

Here's my mvn
Maven home: /Users/greclink1/opensource/apache-maven-3.9.8
Java version: 21.0.3, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.6.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"


Thanks, man, for taking a look into this, but if you see - this is also how I configured the profile in my original post - with activeByDefault=false and then property for activation. And when I run it without the specific parameter - I get the same error I mentioned -  --- fabric8-maven-plugin:4.4.0:build (build-docker-image) @ ..... And I expect to see nothing related to that plugin ...
